# Allowing roles in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an administrator role in ASP.Net configuration named "Administrators" and assigned one user to it, in my web.config I specify this:

```xml
  <location path="Admin/Default.aspx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="Administrators" />
       <deny users="*" />
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
   </location>
```

But it's not working, the user under administrator role is unable to access. Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<allow roles="Administrators" />
```

Roles aren't users.